# Probability of a event in time

Tags: probability

I consistently see the probability P(random variable at time t) = F(random variable before t-1) - F(random variable before t) or some form of this. How do I verify this?

(Sorry if the notation is goofy)

Edit: F is the cdf

Comment: The statement is too loose to allow for any verification.

Comment: what is F? :S :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume here that $F$ is meant to denote some sort of cumulative distribution function for some random variable; it's hard to say, though, because you don't actually have a random variable.

If I was going to more formally write down what I *think* you are trying to say, I'd say your setup is something like this:

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ be events in some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Let $T$ be the minimum number $t$ such that event $A_t$ occurs.

More formally: for $\omega\in\Omega$, define
$$
T(\omega)=\begin{cases}\infty & \text{if }\omega\notin\bigcup_{t=1}^{\infty}A_t\\\min\{t:\ \omega\in A_t\} & \text{else}\end{cases}.
$$

$T$ is now a well-defined random variable.  Let $F$ be its cumulative distribution function:
$$
F(t):=P(T\leq t),\qquad t\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Notice that because only natural-numbered $T$ are allowed, 
$$
P(T\leq t)=\sum_{j=1}^{t}P(T=j)=\sum_{j=1}^{t-1}P(T=j)+P(T=t)=P(T\leq t-1)+P(T=t);
$$
but $P(T\leq t)=F(t)$ and $P(T\leq t-1)=F(t-1)$. So, this says 
$$
F(t)=F(t-1)+P(T=t),
$$
or
$$
P(T=t)=F(t)-F(t-1).
$$
(This result is, of course, completely false if your random variable is allowed to take arbitrary real values instead of discrete integer values.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sorry I wasn't more formal with my question